# Auto-blend Layers on Photoshop or Layers to smart object median/mean stacking for noise reduction image stacking?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop

The title is the question. When trying to make a minimal-noise picture process I use:

- shoot stable burst shots of a scene
- align the shots (with a clumsy homemade python program using Opencv or **worse** the internal auto-align Photoshop feature)
- aligned-shots into layers
- **convert them into a smart object and stacking them using Mean or Median**

I compared that last part to the auto-blend function and it seems that the auto-blend is doing pretty much nothing for noise reduction while stacking mathematically produces the best results.

Best by scene type:

- STATIC: Mean stacking
- MOVEMENT: Median stacking

Worst in both:

- Auto-blend

If Auto-Blend does nothing for noise reduction, what is its use case?

Adobe claims in the description of the feature "Stack Images Blends the best details in each corresponding area. This option works best with aligned layers."

Comment: Hi, because that's the nature of blending (auto or not) when you have for a example a stack of 10 shots of the exact same scene, different only in their noise across the sensor.

When you blend those 10 shots you should get a result in the mean or the median of the values of each pixel.

That's why I'm asking what's the use case of auto-blending if not mathematically blend your images ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Auto-Blend Layers

[Auto-Blend](https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/photoshop/using/combine-images-auto-blend-layers.html) is used to stitch or combine images with smooth transitions in the final composite image. It is intended to blend images for a panorama or collage, or to combine multiple exposures of the same image to extend the depth of field (more of an object in focus).  When using Auto-Blend, Photoshop creates complex layer masks to blend your images together, saving you a lot of masking time.  It is "content aware" like other PS tools that add and remove elements from images.

**Auto-Blend is not well-defined.**   While it is clearly very complex under the covers, Adobe's documentation of the tool is limited and nebulous. For example, describing the "Stack Images" option in Auto-Blend, [Adobe writes](https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/photoshop/using/combine-images-auto-blend-layers.html#:%7E:text=Blends%20the%20best%20details%20in%20each%20corresponding%20area) that it *"Blends the best details in each corresponding area."*  In that sentence, *"Blends"* is ambiguous, *"best"* is subjective, *"details"* is not defined, and what constitutes the boundaries of a *"corresponding area"* is never explained.  Unlike Median Stacking, Auto-Blend is a [Black Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box), best understood based on inputs and outputs, rather than its inner workings.

#### Median Stacking

[Median Stacking](https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/photoshop/using/image-stacks.html#:%7E:text=for%20noise%20reduction-,Median,-The%20median%20channel) is a pixel color "averaging" technique.  It is commonly used to reduce noise from low-light shooting, and can also remove content.  It returns the median channel value for each pixel position across a stack of images (RGB). The tool is not "content aware."

<sub>**Median Stack 1 RGB pixel from 3 Images**</sub>

| Pixel | Red | Green | Blue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Image 1** **Image 2** **Image 3** | `120` 70 150 | `51` 67 45 | 220 140 `145` |
| **Median Values** | **120** | **51** | **145** |

#### Sample Images

Below are 4 images, each with 3 of 4 quadrants out of focus

| Image 1 | Image 2 | Image 3 | Image 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R1C1 in Focus [image] | R1C2 in Focus [image] | R2C1 in Focus [image] | R2C2 in Focus [image] |

| Auto-Blend | Median Stacking |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Below are 4 images, each with 3 of 4 quadrants out of focus and also with color differences

| Image 1 | Image 2 | Image 3 | Image 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R1C1 in Focus [image] | R1C2 in Focus [image] | R2C1 in Focus [image] | R2C2 in Focus [image] |

| Auto-Blend | Median Stacking |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: Thanks, "Stack Images Blends the best details in each corresponding area." is at best a vague description as the content awareness provides benefits only under some strict conditions like you listed above (blurring regions of one same image to simulate focus bracketing is a nice example of a use case). if the auto-blend content awareness seeks only for sharp areas it does pretty much nothing for real life cases stacking outside focus bracketing.

Maybe the definition of the Median was not mandatory to the answer as the question was about the Auto-blend, not basic Math, your time is valuable.

Comment: *"..a vague description"* Agreed [and updated](https://superuser.com/a/1779844/) wanted to speak to that yesterday but no time.  *"it does pretty much nothing for real life cases (of) stacking"*  "Stacking" may (?) be an informal shorthand for output akin to **`Smart Object>Stack Mode`** however even if that is the case, merely including the word "stack" in the "Stack Images" option of "Auto-Blend" should not then be taken to imply any equivalence.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer, that's in fact the close source and black box nature of the feature that lead to me asking this question. Like you said, the description of said feature is really nebulous for me. The use of the expression "best details" is what made me think it would blend well stacked/aligned images possibly better than a median/mean stack. I hope Adobe edits their description, maybe your answer will inspire them.